# NodeJS - Run shell command, exit, transfer to shell command

Tags: node.js, linux, shell, ssh

I want to make a easy Buttonboard in the terminal with node and "blessed" for connection or running different commands.

```
-----------------------------------------------

 _____________________    ___________________
 |   Run cleanup.sh  |    | ssh to server1  |
 _____________________    ___________________

 _____________________    ___________________
 |   Git sync        |    | ssh to server2  |

...
```

I want to click on a Button and the node script runs the command, as example "ssh 10.10.10.10".
The script should exit and I want to be on the server like I would with just running "ssh 10.10.10.10".

Is this possible with nodejs?

The Blessed Script for the buttons is ready, I just don't know how to handle the rest.

Answer (score 0):

use shellJS package with shell.exec() method.

https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs

Handle your script to terminate after each action, like ssh or run sh script.